# How to set two or more AuthenticationProvider in spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Now I will make two AuthenticationProvider for manager and normal user, now I have set manager's AuthenticationProvider,but how to set another AuthenticationProvider for normal user?
Here is the code of the spring security config.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/register/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login/manager").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/hello").hasAuthority("AUTH_WRITE")
            .antMatchers("/world").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/manager/login", authenticationManager()),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}
```

And then, I don't know the AuthenticationManager how to bind the authenticationProvider,can you explain it?